# How to create bottom to top slide menu like app bar in Windows Phone

Tags: wpf, xaml, silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

Hi I need to create a custom bottom to top slide menu... Similar to app bar in Windows Phone. How can I achieve this. Please any point to start?

UI looks as in images below:When the user slides the botton panel the state of bottom panel should change from 1 to 2.... This is very similar control to app bar but I need to add a custom control in that...

[image: This is default state]

[image: This is state after user slide it]

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/SlideView , https://slideview.codeplex.com/ may both will usefull for you :)

Comment: I need a control which I can slide on top of the other.. and not slide with the other control... It should have similar effect like app bar in windows phone..

Comment: i give you way how can you do it just see and try with it Thank You @Balraj Singh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Developing view transitions from scratch is no easy feat, but luckily enough, there are pre-written libraries that can do this for us. The best that I have found so far is called `Transitionals`. You can download the dll from the [Transitionals](http://transitionals.codeplex.com/) page at CodePlex.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <Grid Name="GridDemo">

        <Grid.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="ControlsGrid" 
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Height)"
                        From="0" 
                        To="66" 
                        Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="MouseLeave">
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimation 
                        Storyboard.TargetName="ControlsGrid"
                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="(Grid.Height)"
                        From="66" 
                        To="0" 
                        Duration="0:0:0.5" />
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
        </Grid.Triggers>

        <!-- 
        This is a sample content to demostrate animation;
        Without it 'GridDemo' will be collapsed.
    -->


        <Grid Margin="0" Name="ControlsGrid" VerticalAlignment="Bottom" Background="Black" />
    </Grid>

</Window>
```

Comment: I need this using touch slide event is it possible with that?

Answer (score 0):

I have been able solve this problem by manipulating Translate effect. As shown in the example here http://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/06/06/a-gesture-driven-windows-phone-to-do-application.html?utm_source=tuicool